# replace strings with object from other json files

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I have 3 json files:

1. sources.json
2. destination_level1.json
3. destination_level0.json (final file)

I want to "merge" all theses files by replacing matching strings e.g

destination_level0 -> destination_level1 -> sources

in words: "Check the keys in destination_level0 e.g. "Element1", go to destination_level1 and look for a matching object and replace Element1 in destination_level0 with that object." Same goes on from destination_level1 to sources.

Sources might look like this:

```
{"john": ["A","B"],"mike": ["123","234","345"],"doe": ["abc","cde"],"ann": {"abc": ["yxc","xcv","cvb"],"bcd": ["poi","iuz","uzt"]}}
```

destination_level_1 like this:

```
{"Element1": ["john","ann","john","john","doe","mike"],"Element2": ["ann","mike","ann","doe","doe","doe","ann"],"Element3": ["ann","doe","ann"]}
```

and destination_level_0 like this:

```
{"FinalA": ["Element1","Element2","Element1","Element2","Element2"],"FinalB": ["Element2","Element2","Element2","Element1"]}
```

The final result should look like this:

```
{"FinalA": [[["A","B"],{"abc": ["yxc","xcv","cvb"],"bcd": ["poi","iuz","uzt"]},...
```

I have tried some lodash & underscore, but got stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: From where does element2 come from? From where does finalB come from? The relationships are not clear!

Comment: element2 is manually defined in destination_level0.json. Same for finalB.
element2 should be replaced with the object for element2 from destination_level_1. 
finalB does not need to be replaced as this is the final "key" we will be using. I hope that clarifies it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in pure JavaScript

```js
var sources = {"john": ["A","B"],"mike": ["123","234","345"],"doe": ["abc","cde"],"ann": {"abc": ["yxc","xcv","cvb"],"bcd": ["poi","iuz","uzt"]}};
    var destination_level_0 = {"FinalA": ["Element1","Element2","Element1","Element2","Element2"],"FinalB": ["Element2","Element2","Element2","Element1"]};
    var destination_level_1 = {"Element1": ["john","ann","john","john","doe","mike"],"Element2": ["ann","mike","ann","doe","doe","doe","ann"],"Element3": ["ann","doe","ann"]};
    
    var final = {};
    for(var key in destination_level_0){
        var preFinal = [];
        var elems = destination_level_0[key];
        for(var i in elems){
            var elem = elems[i];
            var names = destination_level_1[elem];
            for(var j in names){
                var name = names[j];
                var finalItem = sources[name];
                preFinal.push(finalItem); 
            }
        }
        final[key] = preFinal;
    }
    
    console.log(final);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(final));
```

Comment: Thanks you very much ... I got it to work - mostly: just one more thing:
How would I be able to nest the lowest level within on "array-item" of the level above? 
E.g. right not is looks like this:
   e.g. for FinalA -> john:
    {"FinalA": [["A","B"],{"abc": ["yxc","xcv","cvb"],"bcd": ["poi","iuz","uzt"]},["A","B"],["A","B"],["abc","cde"],...
I do need the elements from "sources" nested below one item array item e.g. FinalY -> Element1 -> john 
   {"FinalA": [[["A","B"],{"abc": ["yxc","xcv","cvb"],"bcd": ["poi","iuz","uzt"]},["A","B"],["A","B"]],["abc","cde"],

Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. Can you edit your posted question above with an example of your desired output ?

Comment: I think I got it - thank you so much again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Map an item from level0 => level1 => level2 using [`Array#.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) inside `Array#map` (or lodash's [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#map)):

```js
var level0 = {"FinalA": ["Element1","Element2","Element1","Element2","Element2"],"FinalB": ["Element2","Element2","Element2","Element1"]};
var level1 = {"Element1": ["john","ann","john","john","doe","mike"],"Element2": ["ann","mike","ann","doe","doe","doe","ann"],"Element3": ["ann","doe","ann"]};
var level2 = {"john": ["A","B"],"mike": ["123","234","345"],"doe": ["abc","cde"],"ann": {"abc": ["yxc","xcv","cvb"],"bcd": ["poi","iuz","uzt"]}}
;

var result = Object.keys(level0).reduce(function(r, key) {
  r[key] = level0[key].map(function(element) {
    return level1[element].map(function(item) {
      return level2[item];
    });
  }) 
  
  return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```